# How can I check the last letter of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<%= "#{@resource.first_name.capitalize} " + "#{@resource.last_name.capitalize}" + "'s Area" %>
```

which prints stuff like:

> Tom Byrne's Area, or Mark Kelly's Area

It would be really cool though if I could avoid things like:

> Jean Collins's Area, or Paul Harris's Area

and use the correct grammar like:

> Jean Collins' Area, or Paul Harris' Area

Anybody know how I could write some code that would write `"'s Area"` if the last letter of `last_name` is not `"s"`, and write `"' Area"` if it is `"s"`?

Comment: Just thought that I should point out that it's not _technically_ incorrect to use an apostrophe after a name ending with s.  You can choose either style, but you should use your chosen style consistently. See the Chicago Manual of Style, for example: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/PossessivesandAttributives.html?old=PossessivesandAttributives01.html

Comment: Damn!After all that work! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, +1'd them all, as all was useful. In the end I used in a users_helper.rb:

```
  def resource_full_name(name)
    new_name = name + "'"
    if name.end_with?('s')
      return new_name + " Area"
    else
      return new_name + "s Area"
    end
  end
end
```

and then in my view:

```
<%= resource_full_name(@resource.name) %>
```

Comment: Please consider giving your answer the checkmark.  This will help others who find your question to easily see which answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To get the last character of a string: `str[-1]`.

You might look if someone else has done this, since there are several special cases. A quick google search yielded the [possessive gem](https://github.com/bclubb/possessive).

Answer (score 3):

I'd add a method to the model to handle the logic:

```
class ResourceName
  def name_possessive
    last_letter = last_name[-1]
    possesive = last_letter == "s" ? "'" : "'s"

    "#{first_name} #{last_name}#{possessive}"
  end
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= "#{@resource.name_possessive.capitalize}" %> Area
```

This code can be made cleaner, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is an answer to how to remove the `"s"` after `"s'"`, and is not how to do the possessive grammatically. To do it grammatically depends on the pronunciation, not on the spelling (as well as whether the noun is plural or singular), and you would perhaps need a more complicated system that understands the English grammar and holds database of names (perhaps, some fragment of AI) in order to do that.

Pattern matching would be better than counting the position of a character.

```
last_name = "Kelly"
"#{last_name}'s".sub(/(?<=s')s\z/, "")
# => "Kelly's"

last_name = "Harris"
"#{last_name}'s".sub(/(?<=s')s\z/, "")
# => "Harris'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<%= "#{@resource.first_name.capitalize} " + "#{@resource.last_name.capitalize}" + "'s Area" %>
```

You need to determine resource.last_name possessive,

```
class ResourceName
    def poessessive(x)
        p += last_name[-1] == 's' ? "'" : "'s"
    end
end
```

Then you have,

```
<%= "#{@resource.first_name.capitalize} " + "#{@resource.last_name.capitalize}" + "#{@resource.last_name.possessive}" + " Area" %>
```